# AngularJS $resource Custom Action

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I have just started using `$resource` to retrieve data and I'm having problems implementing a custom action.  The standard `GET` is using an object ID as follows;

```
pageContentService.get({ pageId: 1 }, function (data) {
    vm.pageContent = data.content;
});
```

I also want to be able to retrieve the same data using a string as follows;

```
pageContentService.getByPageName({ pageName: "Home" }, function (data) {
    vm.pageContent = data.content;
});
```

My `$resource` service is;

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
    .module("common.services")
    .factory("pageContentService", ["$resource", pageContentService]);

    function pageContentService($resource) {
        return $resource("/api/pageContent/:pageId", null,
            {
                "getByPageName": { method: "GET", url: "/api/pageContent/:pageName", isArray: false }
            });
    };
})();
```

And I have mocked the backend as follows;

```
(function (undefined) {
    "use strict";

    var app = angular.module("pageContentServiceMock", ["ngMockE2E"]);

    app.run(function ($httpBackend) {
        var content = [
            { "pageId": 0, "pageName": "Unknown", "content": "<h1>Page not found</h1>" },
            { "pageId": 1, "pageName": "Home", "content": '<h1>Home Page</h1>' },
            { "pageId": 2, "pageName": "Programs", "content": '<h1>Programs Page</h1>' }
        ];

        var contentUrl = "/api/pageContent";
        $httpBackend.whenGET(contentUrl).respond(content);

        var contentById = new RegExp(contentUrl + "/[0-9][0-9]*", '');
        $httpBackend.whenGET(contentById).respond(function (method, url, data) {
            var pageContent = content[0];
            var parameters = url.split("/");
            var length = parameters.length;
            var pageId = parameters[length - 1];

            if (pageId > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
                    if (content[i].pageId == pageId) {
                        pageContent = content[i];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return [200, pageContent, {}];
        });

        var contentByName = new RegExp(contentUrl + "/[a-z][A-Z]*", '');
        $httpBackend.whenGET(contentByName).respond(function (method, url, data) {
            var pageContent = content[0];
            var parameters = url.split("/");
            var length = parameters.length;
            var pageName = parameters[length - 1];

            if (pageName.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
                    if (content[i].pageName == pageName) {
                        pageContent = content[i];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return [200, pageContent, {}];
        });
    });
})();
```

The code works as expected when using the "pageId" to return the data however it doesn't appear to execute the "getByPageName" action of the service in the latter code.

From my understanding the custom action is used to extend the existing functionality of the standard `$resource` methods so I presume I am not implementing it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with something like this:

```
angular.module('common.services').factory('pageContentService', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return {
            getByPageName: $resource('/api/pageContent/:pageName', {pageName: '@pageName'}, { method: "GET", isArray: false }),
            getByPageId: $resource('/api/pageContent/:id', {id: '@id'}, { method: "GET", isArray: false })
        };
    }
]);
```

And after injecting `pageContentService` in a controller you can retrieve your data by:

```
pageContentService.getByPageName({ pageName: "Home" }, function (data) {
    vm.pageContent = data.content;
});
```

Or:

```
pageContentService.getByPageId({ id: 1 }, function (data) {
    vm.pageContent = data.content;
});
```

Comment: Modified the code as you suggested however neither `getPageById` or `getPageByName` work when called using `pageContentService.getByPageId({ pageId: 1 }, function (data) {vm.pageContent = data.content;});` or `pageContentService.getByPageName({ pageName: "Home" }, function (data) {vm.pageContent = data.content;});`.  NOTE: I did change the `getPageById` to use `pageId` so it was consistent with `getPageByName`.

Comment: Are you sure you can do a GET with this url? `/api/pageContent/:pageName`

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be in the mocking.  I was using;

```
var contentByName = new RegExp(contentUrl + "/[a-z][A-Z]*", '');
```

When I should have been using;

```
var contentByName = new RegExp(contentUrl + "/[a-zA-Z]+", '');
```

Once I fixed that I could use either;

```
pageContentService.get({ pageId: 1 }, function (data) {
    vm.pageContent = data.content;
});
```

To retrieve the data using the default "GET" or;

```
pageContentService.getByPageName({ pageName: "Home" }, function (data) {
    vm.pageContent = data.content;
});
```

To use the custom action.  I also tried Michelem's suggestion using;

```
function pageContentService($resource) {
    return {
        "getByPageId": $resource('/api/pageContent/:pageId', null, { method: "GET", isArray: false }),
        "getByPageName": $resource('/api/pageContent/:pageName', null, { method: "GET", isArray: false })
    };
}
```

But I couldn't get this to work.